# Reuse results of SELECT query inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is probably a very simple question, but my attempts to search for an answer are thwarted by Google finding answers showing how to reuse a query by making a stored procedure instead. I want to reuse the results of a query inside a stored procedure.

Here's a cut-down example where I've chopped out `NOCOUNT`, `XACT_ABORT`, `TRANSACTION`, `TRY`, and much of the logic.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Do_Something
    @userId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM LikedItems
    WHERE likedItemId IN
    (
        SELECT Items.id FROM Items
        WHERE Items.userId = @userId
    )

    DELETE FROM FollowedItems
    WHERE followedItemId IN
    (
        SELECT Items.id FROM Items
        WHERE Items.userId = @userId
    )

END
```

What is the syntax to reuse the results of the duplicated nested `SELECT` rather than doing it twice?

Comment: Tip: You can use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows, e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows. `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket. Note in your case `LikedItems` may only contain a subset of the `Items` for `@userId`. If all `FollowedItems` are also `LikedItems`, or vice versa, then `output` can still be used though the order of deletes may need to be swapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can INSERT result of the SELECT into a temporary table or table variable, but it doesn't automatically mean that the overall performance would be better. You need to measure it.

**Temp Table**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Do_Something
    @userId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #Temp(id int);

    INSERT INTO #Temp(id)
    SELECT Items.id 
    FROM Items
    WHERE Items.userId = @userId;

    DELETE FROM LikedItems
    WHERE likedItemId IN
    (
        SELECT id FROM #Temp
    )

    DELETE FROM FollowedItems
    WHERE followedItemId IN
    (
        SELECT id FROM #Temp
    )

    DROP TABLE #Temp;

END
```

**Table variable**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Do_Something
    @userId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Temp TABLE(id int);

    INSERT INTO @Temp(id)
    SELECT Items.id 
    FROM Items
    WHERE Items.userId = @userId;

    DELETE FROM LikedItems
    WHERE likedItemId IN
    (
        SELECT id FROM @Temp
    )

    DELETE FROM FollowedItems
    WHERE followedItemId IN
    (
        SELECT id FROM @Temp
    )

END
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion that the performance may not be improved. Thanks

Comment: It is not uncommon that performance with temp tables is worse, but it all depends on complexity of queries, where the bottleneck is, and how your `tempdb` is set up.

Answer (score 1):

You  can declare a table variable to store the results of the select and then simply query that.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Do_Something
@userId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TempItems TABLE (id int)
INSERT INTO @TempItems
SELECT Items.id FROM Items
WHERE Items.userId = @userId

DELETE FROM LikedItems
WHERE likedItemId IN
(
    SELECT id FROM @TempItems 
)

DELETE FROM FollowedItems
WHERE followedItemId IN
(
    SELECT id FROM @TempItems 
)

END
```

Answer (score 1):

If the subquery is fast and simple - no need to change anything. Item's data is in the cache (if it was not) after the first query, locks are obtained. If the subquery is slow and complicated - store it into a table variable and reuse by *the same subquery* as listed in the question.

If your question is not related to performance and you are beware of copy-paste: there is no copy-paste. There is the same logic, similar structure and references - yes, you will have almost the same query source code.

In general, it is not the same. Some rows could be deleted from or inserted into Items table after the first query unless your are running under SERIALIZABLE isolation level. Many different things could happen during first delete, between first and second delete statements. Each delete statement also requires it's own execution plan - thus all the information about tables affected and joins must be provided to SERVER anyway. You need to filter by the same source again - yes, you provide subquery with the same source again. There is no "twice" or "reuse" of a partial code. Data collected by a complicated query - yes, it can be reused (*without running the same complicated query* - by *simple querying from prepared source*) via temp tables/table variables as mentioned before.